# Why is my torrc file almost empty?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm trying to set up a hidden service site following the instructions [on the Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en#one) but I can't find the adequate line. This is all that's in my torrc file.

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory C:\Users\randyniuadmin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\randyniuadmin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\randyniuadmin\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
```

Is that normal?

Comment: Are you stuck on the first step **Step One: Install a web server locally**?

Comment: Yeah, I got apache.

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser's `torrc` file is actually a minimalist set of changes made by the user (some of them to correctly set local directories, etc), the base set of configuration choices for tor itself is in the `torrc-defaults` file which is applied first then modified or overridden by the users changes set in the `torrc` file. However even `torrc-defaults` a reduced set and doesn't include the complete output of `torrc` that would be generated by a normal tor build.

As such, under Tor Browser you won't find the commented lines in `torrc` that the documentation describes but adding them yourself will work.

In most cases it's not recommended to run a hidden service from a Tor client that is likely to go on and offline with your own activity (e.g. when you start or stop tor browser) because this would potentially link your being on or offline to the status of the hidden service and thus link your identity and the service together but there is no reason that it *cannot* work and it is indeed a perfectly valid use case under certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden service instructions you linked to should be sufficient. You just need to put the setting keys (e.g. `HiddenServiceDir` or `HiddenServicePort`) into the torrc file yourself. Don't worry if they are not already in the file. (There is no difference between deleting an unused setting from the file, and commenting it out... e.g. `#HiddenServicePort blahblah` is commented out anyway, so as a matter of preference some people just delete unused settings).

You can find a comprehensive list of all the torrc options at the [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), but the hidden service instructions you linked to should be sufficient for your needs.

Using the instructions from the link you provided, for example if you are using Apache running on localhost (`127.0.0.1`) port `8080`, you would append the following lines to your `.torrc` file:

```
HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\randyniuadmin\Documents\tor\hidden_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
```

where `C:\Users\randyniuadmin\Documents\tor\hidden_service` is a writeable directory existing on your machine where Tor can store metadata files (like the onion address of your hidden service).